# Can I skip the require('something') file in webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have one js file that contains the following code.

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
   // For Node.js or CommonJS.
   var Backbone = require('backbone');
   var _ = require('lodash');
   var $ = Backbone.$ = require('jquery');
   module.exports = factory(root, Backbone, _, $);
}
```

So, When I bundle this file with webpack it looks for the dependencies in my node_modules folder. And I don't want to install that dependency in my project. So It throws me an error regarding dependencies not found.

Is there any way to bundle only this file like only appending the file to bundle without resolving the dependencies?

I have tried 'text' loader but it converts whole js file to string.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with these `require` lines if the dependencies are not installed in `node_modules` ?

Comment: I want to skip this lines.